# How can one clone elements and preserve the event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail, clone

I am making a chrome extension to add javascript encryption to Gmail for my buddies and I personal use. I have most of it working except for when I try to clone a button already in the Gmail interface by doing `$('#elmId').clone(true)`, it doesn't clone the event listeners. Also, `$('#elmId').data('events')` comes up with nothing. I know that the button has multiple event listeners because when I inspect element the developer tools shows it has click, mouseover, etc. under the "Event Listeners" tab (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KnIW.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDln6.png). Is this even possible? I'v done quite a bit of searching and have come up with nothing. Any ideas on how to do this or if it is even possible?

Answer (score -1):

Even if cloning the event listener is technically possible it doesn't mean it's meaningful. The listener may be a closure that knows about the element, using the same closure on a different element is not going to work... for example

```
x.onclick = function(){document.body.removeChild(x);}
```

in this case the `onclick` handler removes the element `x`, but if you copy the element and the handler clicking the copy would still close the original.